# Triangle properties from vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, triangles

I am a beginner at linear algebra and I am still trying to connect the dots. I stumbled upon this problem and I had no idea how can I approach it. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

[image: Question]

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to approach linear algebra: Visually and algebraically. If you're struggling I suggest to try the visual approach. In this case: Try to simplify the problem!

A triangle is 2 dimensional, so it exists on a plane, that's enough to give you a decent visualisation. Do you know what the length of each of these vectors is? How would that affect the triangle?

Comment: That is more a comment than an answer!

Comment: I would agree, but I wouldn't know how to go more in-depth without giving the result away :P

Comment: So I can solve for the angles using this rule: A⋅B=|A||B|cosθ ?

Comment: You could. But there's an in-product used here, which you won't be coming across until much later in your course. 

What you may have come across so far is the triangle inequality, which says that if we have a triangle with sides $a, b, c$, then $$|a|+|b|\leq |c|$$ Can you see why this would be true? Can you also see how it may affect your triangle?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: For a point A$$A={ \begin{bmatrix}A_x\\A_y\\A_z
\end{bmatrix}}$$
Giving You $$\vec A=-2\vec i-6\vec j+3\vec k$$
$$\vec B=\vec i+3\vec j-12\vec k$$
$$\vec C=\vec i+3\vec j+9\vec k$$

Hope it explains enough about your triangle?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't fully understand

Comment: These gives you the points A,B and C in space. You can make a triagnle with $\vec {AB} , \vec{BC}$and$ \vec{CA}$.  Now applying Vector algebra, You can determine your type of Triangle. If you need help iwth that, Please let me know. @AbuBakr

Comment: How did you derive those equations from the vectors?

Comment: @AbuBakr sorry. I did not get you question. Please elaborate again.

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out the internal angles of the triangles for one $A\cdot B = |A||B|\cos\theta$ (Which will tell you if it's equilateral/isosceles etc). You can also figure out its area $\frac{1}{2}|\vec{AB}\times\vec{AC}|$ etc. I'm not entirely sure what the question meant as it was pretty vague, but those are the first things that come to mind.

Comment: The question asks whether it's an equilateral/isosceles or an acute triangle

Comment: In which case, figure out the angles and side lengths!